# add '%' sign to all ticks on y-axis using nvd3.js library without multiplying by 100

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3.js library to show line chart.

I need to add '%' sign next to ticks on y-axis. I know that I can format nvd3 to use format like

```
  chart.yAxis
            .axisLabel("Y-axis Label")
            .tickFormat(d3.format(".0%"))
        ;
```

but this will convert y-values like 0.1 to 10% ( I mean this will multiply all values by 100, but I do not need this). But I do not need this conversion, I just need to add '%' sign without any conversion. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
chart.yAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    var formatter = d3.format(".0%");
    return formatter(d)
});
```

OR

```
formatter = d3.format(".0%");
chart.yAxis.tickFormat(formatter);
```

**UPDATE :**

```
chart.yAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d + '%'
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is exactly the same I already wrote above. This multiplies all values by 100 that I do not need. I just need to add "%" sign and not multiplying ticks by 100.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code in adding here.

```
chart.yAxis
    .axisLabel("Y-axis Label")
    .tickFormat(d => `${d3.format('.0')(d)} %`);
```